# How to find missing numbers in a sequence?

Tags: r

I have a vector containing a list of numbers. How do I find numbers that are missing from the vector?

For example:

```
sequence <- c(12:17,1:4,6:10,19)
```

The missing numbers are 5, 11 and 18.

Comment: Use setdiff() to compare sequence with min(sequence):max(sequence)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sequence <- c(12:17,1:4,6:10,19)

seq2 <- min(sequence):max(sequence)

seq2[!seq2 %in% sequence]
```

...and the output:

```
> seq2[!seq2 %in% sequence]
[1]  5 11 18
>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `setdiff()` function to compute set differences. You want the difference between the complete sequence (from `min(sequence)` to `max(sequence)`) and the `sequence` with missing values.

```
setdiff(min(sequence):max(sequence), sequence)
```

Comment: Just a note, if your sequence is `seq <- c(8,4,2,5,6)` and you use this code it will not recognise "1" missing from the sequence since `min(seq) = 2`; a similar situation can occur if it's the last number missing. In those cases, you should set the known min and max values e.g., `setdiff(1:max(seq), seq)`

Answer (score 1):

This answer just gets all of the numbers from the lowest to highest in the sequence, then asks which are not present in the original sequence.

```
which(!(seq(min(sequence), max(sequence)) %in% sequence))
[1]  5 11 18
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect if `min(sequence)` is different than `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
c(1:max(sequence))[!duplicated(c(sequence,1:max(sequence)))[-(1:length(sequence))]]
[1]  5 11 18
```

Not a particularly elegant solution, I admit, but what it does is determines which in the vector 1:max(sequence) are duplicates of sequence, and then selects those out of that same vector.